# How to extract the website URL from the redirect link with Scrapy Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a script to get the data from a website. I have issue with collecting the website URL since the @href is the redirect link. How can I convert the redirect URL to the actual website it's redirecting to?

```
import scrapy
import logging


class AppSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'app'
    allowed_domains = ['www.houzz.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.houzz.in/professionals/searchDirectory?topicId=26721&query=Design-Build+Firms&location=Mumbai+City+District%2C+India&distance=100&sort=4']

    def parse(self, response):
        lists = response.xpath('//li[@class="hz-pro-search-results__item"]/div/div[@class="hz-pro-search-result__info"]/div/div/div/a')
        for data in lists:
            link = data.xpath('.//@href').get()

            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_houses, meta={'Links': link})

        next_page = response.xpath('(//a[@class="hz-pagination-link hz-pagination-link--next"])[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_houses(self, response):
        link = response.request.meta['Links']

        firm_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__title"]/h1/text()').get()
        name = response.xpath('//div[@class="profile-meta__val"]/text()').get()
        phone = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__contact-info text-right mrm"]/a/span/text()').get()
        website = response.xpath('(//div[@class="hz-profile-header__contact-info text-right mrm"]/a)[2]/@href').get()

        yield {
            'Links': link,
            'Firm_name': firm_name,
            'Name': name,
            'Phone': phone,
            'Website': website
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to have do a request to that target URL to see where it leads to

In your case, you can do simply the `HEAD` request, that will not load any body of target URL so that will save bandwidth and increase speed of your script as well

```
def parse_houses(self, response):
    link = response.request.meta['Links']

    firm_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__title"]/h1/text()').get()
    name = response.xpath('//div[@class="profile-meta__val"]/text()').get()
    phone = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__contact-info text-right mrm"]/a/span/text()').get()
    website = response.xpath('(//div[@class="hz-profile-header__contact-info text-right mrm"]/a)[2]/@href').get()

    yield Request(url=website, 
        method="HEAD", 
        callback=self.get_final_link,
        meta={'data': 
                {
                'Links': link,
                'Firm_name': firm_name,
                'Name': name,
                'Phone': phone,
                'Website': website
            }
        }
        )


def get_final_link(self, response):
    data = response.meta['data']
    data['website'] = response.headers['Location']
    yield data
```

If your goal is to get the website, that actual website link is available in source-code of each listing as well, you can grab it by regex, no need to visit the encrypted url

```
def parse_houses(self, response):
    link = response.request.meta['Links']

    firm_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__title"]/h1/text()').get()
    name = response.xpath('//div[@class="profile-meta__val"]/text()').get()
    phone = response.xpath('//div[@class="hz-profile-header__contact-info text-right mrm"]/a/span/text()').get()
    website = re.findall(r"\"url\"\: \"(.*?)\"", response.text)[0]
```

Comment: @AwaisAhmedSheikh see my edited answer again, you can get website from ad page as well, no need to open the encrypted link

Answer (score 0):

you can do st like this:

```
class AppSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    base_url = 'www.houzz.in{}'
    .
    .
    .
    def foo(self):
        actual_url = self.base_url.format(redirect_url)
```